# python matplotlib pip install amazon ec2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, matplotlib, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install matplotlib on my ubuntu aws ec2 instance:

```
sudo pip install matplotlib
```

I did install these:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev libffi-dev
```

and I still get this error:

```
ubuntu@ip-102-21-11-112:~$ sudo pip install matplotlib
The directory '/home/ubuntu/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/ubuntu/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting matplotlib
  Downloading matplotlib-2.0.0-1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (14.6MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 14.6MB 93kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7.1 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: functools32 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.0,!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=1.5.6 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from matplotlib)
Collecting subprocess32 (from matplotlib)
  Downloading subprocess32-3.2.7.tar.gz (54kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 11.9MB/s 
Installing collected packages: subprocess32, matplotlib
  Running setup.py install for subprocess32 ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-d910Y8/subprocess32/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-1nVmds-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    copying subprocess32.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    running build_ext
    building '_posixsubprocess' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _posixsubprocess.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_posixsubprocess.o
    unable to execute 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc': No such file or directory
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-d910Y8/subprocess32/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-1nVmds-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-d910Y8/subprocess32/
```

Answer (score 1):

you need:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the first line of your error, it clearly states:

> The directory '/home/ubuntu/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory
>   is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled.
>   Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing
>   pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

So try:

`sudo -H pip install matplotlib`

Also check if you have installed setuptools.